# which adverb modifies which adverb?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

There are two sentences:

> It is not necessarily good.

(I think it means: it may be bad)

and

> It is necessarily not good.

(I think it means: it must be bad)

I think **not** modifies **necessarily** in previous sentence, **necessarily** modifies **not** in latter one. So, the two sentences mean different things.

Is my understanding right?

Then, I have some specific questions:

1. These both have same means?
2. In the both sentences, **not** modifies **necessarily**?
3. In general rule, doesn't previous adverb modify latter adverb ?
4. Or, is there some general rules but some specific special ?

Comment: Your understanding is correct, so the answers to 1) and 2) are both *no*.

Comment: I have the question because google translate give me same result by Chinese? So I have some little bit doubt.

Comment: I do not know any Chinese, but I suspect you typed the same thing into Google Translate twice. When I do it, I get two different results. [Link 1](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=zh-TW&text=It%20is%20not%20necessarily%20good.&op=translate), [Link 2](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=zh-TW&text=It%20is%20necessarily%20not%20good.&op=translate)

Comment: In chinese, both results mean same thing.

Comment: In English, the two sentences do **not** mean the same thing.